# wheezy-updates on archive.debian.org returns 404 Not Found

Tags: debian, apt, debian-wheezy, archive

I have an old test machine on Debian Wheezy that I can't really update right now.

Debian Wheezy repositories were archived in February. So I want ahead, and updated my `/etc/apt/sources.list` from

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main
```

to

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main
```

But, when running `apt-get update`, I'm getting this error:

```
# apt-get update
<snip>
Err http://archive.debian.org wheezy-updates/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP : 193.62.202.28 80]
```

Other repositories are being updated without issues.

Am I missing something?

Comment: wheezy is EOL, please _seriously_ consider upgrading to a supported release.

Comment: There isn't such a repository in the archive. It's years past time to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the remember! It's a test machine which live on my PC (it's a VM) which is not accessible from the Internet (not even from my LAN). I'll probably rebuild it from scratch in the near future with an up-to-date Debian. Of course, if it was a production machine, it would have already been upgraded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the [Debian archive](http://archive.debian.org) you shouldn't have an apt source line referring to `wheezy-updates`.  This particular (sub-)distribution is not existing in the archives.

If you just **remove the lines**:

```
deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian wheezy-updates main
```

you should be able to run your `apt-get` commands again.

### The whole story

The `wheezy-updates` repository contained packages that were provided to update the main repository, i.e. `wheezy`, between minor releases.  Over time, when Wheezy got updated to 7.1, 7.2 and eventually to 7.11, the packages contained in `wheezy-updates` were moved into the main Wheezy repository.  When Wheezy got EOLed, in May 2018, no packages were being kept in `wheezy-updates`, so there was no point in moving `wheezy-updates` to the Debian archive.

You can see the list of all Debian distributions supported by the archive repository at: 
http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/  Also check the README files at http://archive.debian.org/README and http://archive.debian.org/debian/README to have an even fuller list of the archive content.

With regards to the `security.debian.org` repository, it is archived as well at http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/  If you want to fetch the very last updates, dating from May 2018, that were published for Wheezy, you can also **add this line** to your apt sources:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ wheezy/updates main
```

### Caution

Like said in the comments to your question, **be careful when running a machine using the Debian archive as those packages are not updated and so not secure anymore (even when using debian-security from the archive)**.  It probably is OK if your machine is not directly connected to a network, but otherwise, I would highly recommend upgrading as soon as possible.

Comment: “The same goes for the security.debian.org repository, as Wheezy is EOL, you'll get no packages from there.” AFAICT this is not true. The security repo in http://archive.debian.org/debian-security contains Perl 5.14.2-21+deb7u6, but the main repo in http://archive.debian.org/debian only contains 5.14.2-21+deb7u3.

Comment: True, thanks for your comment.  I amended my answer to better reflect that.  But those _security_ packages are now out of date as well, thus bring little value.

Answer (score 9):

Add the security updates:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main
```

Answer (score 4):

If like me you are dealing with an embedded wheezy system and just need to make something work, here are the complete steps that worked for me.

The original sources no longer exist which causes the 404 error (not found), so we need to modify the source list. Remove the original line add the two archive lines.

```
vi /etc/apt/sources.list
    deb http://archive.debian.org/debian wheezy main
    deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security wheezy/updates main
```

Change the date back to before the security certificate expired.

```
 date +%Y%m%d -s "20180101"
```

Update list.

```
apt-get update -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false;
```

Install stuff.

```
apt-get install nano inotify-tools msmtp   -o Acquire::Check-Valid-Until=false;
```

No guarantee how long this will work for, but it worked for me in May 2020. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Could you explain how changing the system date fixes an HTTP 404 error?

Comment: You need to remove the original sources in /etc/apt/sources.list as they no longer exist. The two previous answers covered this. Changing the date tricks apt-get into accepting the expired source list.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, too.  Thanks.

Comment: Works for me too. Can you explain what the side-effects of date +%Y%m%d -s "20180101" are?

Comment: @tersmitten It depends on how paranoid you are about security. There's a certificate that the program you are running (apt-get in this case) uses to verify that the server it's talking to is who it says it is. Those certificates expire and have to renewed regularly.

Comment: Since this library has been archived, no one is going to bother updating the certificate. Which means that any devices pulling software from there cannot properly verify that the server is who it says it is. If a bad actor somehow hijacks the server and the certificate, you might end up with malicious software on your device. Use are your own risk. Make sure you change the date back after you are done.

Comment: Still working in 2021. Thanks alot!!