# Setting up a local mirror

Tags: debian-wheezy

Specifically for Wheezy, does anyone know if some of the existing mirror scripts still work or can point me in the right direction to start?

For example, will Debmirror work with archive.debian.org?
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Debmirror

I've installed the latest debmirror to my Ubuntu 16 "mirror server" (my working local Ubuntu 16 mirror and hoping it can also be a local Wheezy mirror).

I'm assuming it does some kind of "rsync over http".  A small section of the error output:

```
+ debmirror -a i386 --no-source -s main,restricted,universe,multiverse -h archive.debian.org -d wheezy,wheezy-security,wheezy-updates -r /debian --progress --method=http /[REMOVED]/DebianMirror
Mirroring to /array0/DebianMirror from http://archive.debian.org/debian/
Arches: i386
Dists: wheezy,wheezy-security,wheezy-updates
Sections: main,restricted,universe,multiverse
Pdiff mode: use
Will clean up after mirroring.
Attempting to get lock ...
Updating remote trace files (using rsync) ...
rsync: failed to connect to archive.debian.org (217.196.149.234): Connection refused (111)
...
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at clientserver.c(128) [Receiver=3.1.1]
Warning: failed to use rsync to download extra files.
Getting meta files ...
[  0%] Getting: dists/wheezy/Release...          #** GET http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/Release ==> 500 Status read failed: Connection reset by peer (1s)
failed 500 Status read failed: Connection reset by peer
...
failed 500 Status read failed: Connection reset by peer
Errors:
 Download of dists/wheezy/Release failed: 500 Status read failed: Connection reset by peer
...
Failed to download some Release, Release.gpg or InRelease files!
WARNING: releasing 1 pending lock...
```

Answer (score 0):

apt-mirror seems to work fine:
https://blog.programster.org/create-your-own-debian-7-mirror

I was thrown off by a network issue, but it seems to work fine with archive.debian.org.

Comment: The above will help you, but also this to get the archived security updates: https://serverfault.com/questions/960970/wheezy-updates-on-archive-debian-org-returns-404-not-found